# Typescript even with array type is specified, splice show never

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, interface, vuex

I have an interface that contains an array:

```
export interface AnimationCanvasState {
  frames: Array<Frame>
}
```

The frames array def has the type `Frame`.

I applied this interface to a vuex state:

```
const state: AnimationCanvasState = {
  frames: [],
}


export const animationCanvas: Module<AnimationCanvasState, RootState> = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
}
```

My problem is when I try to splice data into the array in a mutation:

```
export enum AnimationCanvasMutations {
  ADD_FRAME = "ADD_FRAME"
}

export const mutations: MutationTree<AnimationCanvasState> = {
  [AnimationCanvasMutations.ADD_FRAME] (state, index:number | undefined) {

        if (index !== undefined) {
            state.frames.splice(index, 0, new Frame(8, 8));
        } else {
            state.frames.push(new Frame(8, 8));
        }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:
[image]

I've looked up errors like this and all of the solutions seem to say "you need to type your array", but I did this. I can confirm that the `state.frames` is indeed typed:

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why the complier would see this array type as never when it's definitely typed in the interface. Any thoughts?

Comment: please share reproducable example

Comment: Never mind, it seems to have been some issue with chrome or the typescript compiler. I quit out of vscode and chrome, started each back up, and the error went away, no code changes :|